# can we take table name as an input from the client using php

Tags: php

it's showing an syntax error message in line 18 help me out to solve it
and i really want a table name by client so what i have to do if this piece of code don't work and first of all is it possible to take name of the table from the user or the client?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['table']))
{
    $server="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="major";
    
    $con=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
    
    if (!$con)
    {
        die("failed". mysqli_connect_erre());
    }
    
    $table=$_POST['table'];
    $sql="create table '$table'(id int,name varchar(5))";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    
    if($result==true)
    {
        echo"sucess";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"error";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="new.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name=table id=table>
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `mysqli_connect_erre()`?

Comment: Table names should be surrounded by backticks, not single or double quotes. Quotes are only for values. That said, I'd really suggest checking the table against an acceptable list of values before actually using it.

Comment: `an syntax error message in line 18`, what is the message?